# I can't get Mylyn to save current context using pydev

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I'm starting using eclipse with PyDev, and I want to use Mylyn.

However, when I'm working on an active task, Mylyn is not saving the opened files in context.
I press right button on my active task, go to "context" option, and I noticed every option is disabled.

Any clue?

Comment: maybe this is related to [When I use Mylyn with PyDev I see the context in the task but python files are not shown in any explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459068)