# Context tab not visible in Eclipse Mylyn for Local Repository

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I have installed Eclipse Juno for Linux. I wanted to experiment with Mylyn, but when I create a new task, the Context tab doesn't show up. It is in my "local" repository.

Is the context supposed to work with the "local" repository? In older versions of Eclipse it seemed to.

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841961/i-cant-get-mylyn-to-save-current-context-using-pydev)

Answer (score 1):

I used File->Import->Install->From Existing Installation when upgrading to Juno. I wasn't careful in selecting plugins to include and overwrote a newer Mylyn with an older copy. Re-install from scratch and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This also can happen if you install the wrong version of Mylyn for your Eclipse distro, as I just found out!