# When I use Mylyn with PyDev I see the context in the task but python files are not shown in any explorer

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, mylyn

I use mylyn 3.9.0 with PyDev 2.7.5 with the PyDev Mylyn integration 0.4.0.

Mylyn seems to build up contexts correctly  (I can see the context tree in the task/context tab). But the python files are not shown "PyDev Package Explorer" nor in the "Project Explorer".

What could prevent the python files to appear?

Uninstalling the PyDev Mylyn integration did not help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the "PyDev Navigator Content".

Ho to solve this

- make sure the Mylyn focus is disabled for the explorer view
- in the View Menu -> Customise View
- on the "Content" tab disable "PyDev Navigator Content"

==> now the python files are shown correctly when the Mylyn context is enabled

*Note:* This works in both: the "PyDev Package Explorer" and in the "Project Explorer"

You may add `*.pyc` to Preferences->Mylyn->Context->Resources -- this will prevent the pyc files to appear in your context when they are compiled automatically...